# Tensor notation for a vector function

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors

The index of a variable indicates its transformation properties. Does it make sense to denote the components of a vector function as $f^i(x)$, i.e. as a contravariant tensor? Since a vector function does not represent a system of coordinates it is not the case that under a different coordinate system $\bar{x}$,
\begin{equation}
\bar{f}^i(\bar{x}) = \frac{\partial \bar{x}^i}{\partial x^j}f^j(x)
\end{equation}
Is indexing for a vector function a matter of taste?

Comment: Who knows! The components of a vector function could easily be the coefficients of a $1$-form (covariant tensor) just as they could be the coefficients of a vector field (contravariant tensor).

Comment: @Ted Shifrin How would you prove that a vector field is a contravariant tensor?

Comment: Virtually by definition. When you write $V = \sum f^i(x)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, then we have $V = \sum \bar f^j\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar x^j} = \sum\bar f^j \sum\dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial\bar x^j}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, and so $$f^i = \sum\bar f^j \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\bar x^j},$$ as required.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin , take a vector field in two dimensions $\mathbf{f}(x,y)=(x-y,x^2+y^2)$. Say you do a simple linear coordinate transformation $x'=x-y$ and $y'=(x+y)/2$. I cannot see how your last equation holds.

Comment: Show me the calculation. What are $\partial/\partial x’$ and $\partial/\partial y’$ and the components of $\mathbf f$ in terms of $(x’,y’)$?

Comment: In the r.h.s. of your equation $$ f^1 = \bar{f}^1 \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial \bar{x}^1 }+ \bar{f}^2 \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial \bar{x}^2 }$$. From the definitions, $ \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial \bar{x}^1 }=1/2$ and $\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial \bar{x}^2 }=1$. Since in terms of $x,y$, $\bar{f}^1(x',y')=f^1(x,y)$ and $\bar{f}^2(x',y')=f^2(x,y)$ we have $$f^1=x-y$$ on the l.h.s. and $$(x-y)/2+x^2+y^2$$ on the r.h.s. So your last equation does not hold.

Comment: Absolutely not. What makes you think $\bar f^i = f^i$? If that were so, you would have the transformation for *functions* (i.e., tensors of rank $0$), not for the components of a vector field.

Comment: OK Just to understand: for the specific example I gave, if I start with $\mathbf{f}(x,y)=(x-y,x^2+y^2)$ and I apply the transformation $x'=x-y,y'=(x+y)/2$ what is $\bar{\mathbf{f}}$?

Comment: You have to actually work out the components of the vector field in terms of the basis $\partial/\partial x'$ and $\partial/\partial y'$, precisely as in my derivation of the formula. I suggest you go back and read about the basics.

Comment: OK so in my example since $\mathbf{f}(x,y)=(x-y,x^2+y^2)$ and $$\bar{f}^i=f^j \frac{\partial \bar{x}^i}{\partial x^j}$$ we have $$\bar{f}^1=(x-y)-(x^2+y^2)$$ and $$\bar{f}^2=(x-y)/2+(x^2+y^2)/2$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for the sake of progress, here's the complete solution.  With your
\begin{align*}
x' &= x-y \\
y' &= \frac12(x+y), 
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac12 x' + y' \\
y &= -\frac12 x' + y',
\end{align*}
and so $x-y = x'$ and $x^2+y^2 = \frac12 x'{}^2 + 2y'{}^2$.
As we said earlier, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} \quad\text{and} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &= \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{(x-y)}_{f^1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \underbrace{(x^2+y^2)}_{f^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &=
x'\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}+\frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\right) + (\tfrac12x'{}^2 + 2y'{}^2)\left(-\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\right) \\
&=\underbrace{(x'-\tfrac12x'{}^2-2y'{}^2)}_{\bar f^1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \underbrace{\left(\tfrac12x' + \tfrac14x'{}^2 +y'{}^2\right)}_{\bar f^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}.
\end{align*}

Comment: It is interesting that in the definition of the vector field the basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$ are replaced by covariant partial derivatives. I did not realise this , for some reason I thought a vector field was just another vector expression like $\mathbf{v}=v^i \mathbf{e}_i$.

Comment: I dare you to define $\mathbf e_i$ in the setting of a manifold. You should also go back and grok my very first comment.

Comment: As you pointed out I have to do a lot of reading...

Comment: I think the main confusion comes from the fact that for the tangent space of a surface I expect to see partial derivatives of the position vector; instead all I see here is operators.

Comment: Note that these are the same thing when you have a position vector — i.e., when you have a submanifold of Euclidean space.

Comment: Apologies but how can $\frac{\partial \mathbf{p}}{\partial x^i}$ be the same as $\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}$? The only way I can understand the second expression is that perhaps it applies on a scalar function and in the process creates something like the first expression. A vector field is defined over the tangent space of some surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so how can it be an operator?

Comment: You truly need to read some introductory differentiable manifolds/differential geometry texts. Vector fields act on functions by taking directional derivatives.

Comment: Dear Sir -- From Kristopher Tapp's introductory book on differential geometry (page 152): A vector field on a regular surface $S$ means a smooth map $v:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. It is called a tangent field if $v(p) \in T_pS$ for all $p\in S$. It is called a normal field if for all $p\in S$ , $v(p)$ is a normal vector to $S$ at $p$.

Comment: OK, not a curves and surfaces undergraduate text. You need a more advanced book. The issue is the definition of the tangent space of an abstract manifold, not a surface in $\Bbb R^3$. I suggest Spivak, *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, volume 1, or Boothby's differentiable manifolds book, or — newer — J. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* or L. Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds*.

Comment: Spivak is very hard work, any recommendations for someone with a physics background?

Comment: Thanks. There also seems to be a very good book available in pdf form, "Differential Geometry: A First Course in Curves and Surfaces" by Theodore Shifrin!

Comment: Yeah, but that also is undergraduate curves and surfaces. If you want to actually understand what goes on in tensor analysis, you need a more abstract treatment. I never want to teach coordinate charts and transformations in an undergraduate curves-and-surfaces course. You might try this lovely book: Paul Renteln's *Manifolds, Tensors, and Forms: An Introduction for Mathematicians and Physicists*. Paul was a student of mine when he took undergraduate differential geometry; he went on to do a Ph.D. in physics at Harvard.

Comment: Thanks for your help!